# How to add new prototype method / property to imported library module in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Types;

// adds new getter property to ObjectId's prototype
Object.defineProperty(ObjectId.prototype, 'hex', {
  get() {
    return this.__id || (this.__id = this.toHexString());
  },
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
});
```

How to add `hex` to mongoose.Types.ObjectId class in typescript?

types of 'mongoose' are imported via `@types/mongoose`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use module augmentation to add properties to `ObjectId`. The problem in this case is to find where `ObjectId` actually resides.

If we look at the definition of `ObjectId` in `mongoose.Types` we find:

```
var ObjectId: ObjectIdConstructor;
type ObjectIdConstructor = typeof mongodb.ObjectID & {
  (s?: string | number): mongodb.ObjectID;
};
```

So the return type of `new ObjectId()` will actually be `mongodb.ObjectID`, so let's see how that looks:

```
export { ObjectID /* … */} from 'bson';
```

So, here we find `ObjectID` is just a reexport from `'bson'`, if we look at the definition in `bson` we finally find the class definition:

```
export class ObjectID { … }
```

Putting it all together we get:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Types;

declare module "bson" {
    export interface ObjectID {
        hex: string
    }
}

// adds new getter property to ObjectId's prototype
Object.defineProperty(ObjectId.prototype, 'hex', {
  get() {
    return this.__id || (this.__id = this.toHexString());
  },
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
});

new ObjectId().hex
```